# Original proof of the existence of Seifert surfaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, seifert-surfaces

I read on Wikipedia that Frankl and Prontrjagin were the first to prove that a link $\mathbb{R}^3$ bounds a surface. A few years later Seifert published a proof using the "Seifert algorithm" which seems to be the proof preferred in text books on knot theory.  I was wondering if anyone knows an English reference for the original proof or any information about its flavor.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5):

You ask for an English translation of the 1930 paper in German by Frankl and Prontrjagin. There are many such translation requests on MO, so as an experiment, I tried the following: I found a [high-quality scan](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/franpont.pdf) of the paper, OCR'd it and gave it to Google Translate. No editing on my part. Here is the resulting [text](http://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/Frankl_Prontrjagin_translated.txt). Together with the original text for the formulas, it seems workable to me. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture of the Frankl-Pontrjagin construction, from a paper by Lucien Guillou and Alexis Marin:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/6qg1x.png

The inscription reads: "The Frankl-Pontryagin surface of the trefoil knot is depicted with two 'windows' showing what happens inside."

The picture is accompanied in the paper by an actual exposition of a generalization of the Frankl-Pontrjagin construction. This is section 4 of Guillou and Marin's comments 'On the second paper' by Rokhlin in their book "A la Recherche de la Topologie Perdue" (in French; the scan above is from the Russian translation).

Comment: "Dva okoshka" has more charm than the plain "two windows. :-)

Comment: I think the picture is broken, sadly making this answer useless :(